# How to determine the number that when multiplied will get you the closest to a target number?

Tags: javascript, math

Let's say I have the number **2062** and the multiplier is **0.75**

What is the JavaScript formula to find which number that, when multiplied by **0.75**, will come the closest to **2062**?

PS: The closest here means either equal (==) or very close, but **below** the target number, and not very close but **above**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findFactor(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(a / parseFloat(b));
}

findFactor(2062, 0.75) -> 2749
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0s8cr5gd/

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `x` in `x * 0.75 = 2062`.  So solving for `x` that should be `x = 2062 / 0.75`.  To ensure that the number is the closest whole number less than or equal to x, you can use `Math.floor`:

```
Math.floor(2062 / 0.75) = 2749
```